# How to limit the number of shortest path in igraph/R

Tags: r, graph, igraph, shortest-path

Using the `shortest.paths` function we get the shortest path from a graph. Now, I want to limit the length of the shortest path.

For example, when I am running the below code, I am getting all the shortest paths from a vertex to any vertex.

```
df <- read.csv("~/data.csv")
g1 <- df
graph1 <- graph_from_data_frame(g1, directed = FALSE)
plot(graph1, vertex.label = V(graph1)$name)
mat <- shortest.paths(graph1)
```

The output I am getting

```
       ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_8 ID_5 ID_7 ID_100
ID_1      0    1    1    1  Inf    2    2    Inf
ID_2      1    0    2    1  Inf    1    2    Inf
ID_3      1    2    0    2  Inf    3    1    Inf
ID_4      1    1    2    0  Inf    2    1    Inf
ID_8    Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf    0  Inf  Inf      1
ID_5      2    1    3    2  Inf    0    3    Inf
ID_7      2    2    1    1  Inf    3    0    Inf
ID_100  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf    1  Inf  Inf      0
```

But, I want to keep only (say) the path length is 3 and the other will be `0 or Inf`. Actually, I do not need other except (path length =3).

Moreover, I want the `sum of the path weight` not only the number of the path. I thought I Can do this just by changing only one line

```
mat <- shortest.paths(graph1, weights=E(graph1)$weight)
```

But, how can limit the path length?

Reproducible Data

```
structure(list(nodeA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L), .Label = c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_8"), class = "factor"), 
    nodeB = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("ID_100", 
    "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_7"), class = "factor"), 
    weight = c(0.5, 0.77, 0.5, 0.9, 0.44, 0.32, 0.45, 0.543)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: You can simply replace large values in the output. If you are looking for better performance in large graphs, add a comment/vote for the relevant issue in the igraph issue tracker, and link back to this post: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/720

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But, I did not get your point. Is it possible to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `shortest.path` on the data you provided returns directly shortest path (the minimum sum of the path weight) for all nodes combinations.

```r
g1 <- structure(list(nodeA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                         5L), .Label = c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_8"), class = "factor"), 
                     nodeB = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("ID_100", 
                                                                                     "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_7"), class = "factor"), 
                     weight = c(0.5, 0.77, 0.5, 0.9, 0.44, 0.32, 0.45, 0.543)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                    -8L))
library(igraph)

graph1 <- graph_from_data_frame(g1, directed = FALSE)
plot(graph1, vertex.label = V(graph1)$name)
```

[image]

```r
mat <- shortest.paths(graph1)
mat
#>        ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4  ID_8 ID_5 ID_7 ID_100
#> ID_1   0.00 0.50 0.77 0.50   Inf 1.40 0.95    Inf
#> ID_2   0.50 0.00 1.21 0.44   Inf 0.90 0.89    Inf
#> ID_3   0.77 1.21 0.00 0.77   Inf 2.11 0.32    Inf
#> ID_4   0.50 0.44 0.77 0.00   Inf 1.34 0.45    Inf
#> ID_8    Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf 0.000  Inf  Inf  0.543
#> ID_5   1.40 0.90 2.11 1.34   Inf 0.00 1.79    Inf
#> ID_7   0.95 0.89 0.32 0.45   Inf 1.79 0.00    Inf
#> ID_100  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf 0.543  Inf  Inf  0.000

library(reshape)

edges <- melt(mat)
edges[as.character(edges$X1)>as.character(edges$X2)&!is.infinite(edges$value),]
     X1     X2 value
2  ID_2   ID_1 0.500
3  ID_3   ID_1 0.770
4  ID_4   ID_1 0.500
6  ID_5   ID_1 1.400
7  ID_7   ID_1 0.950
11 ID_3   ID_2 1.210
12 ID_4   ID_2 0.440
14 ID_5   ID_2 0.900
15 ID_7   ID_2 0.890
20 ID_4   ID_3 0.770
22 ID_5   ID_3 2.110
23 ID_7   ID_3 0.320
30 ID_5   ID_4 1.340
31 ID_7   ID_4 0.450
47 ID_7   ID_5 1.790
61 ID_8 ID_100 0.543
```

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, ID_3 and ID_5 are at a distance of path length =3. You are right. But, the problem is, I can not `prune/reduce` the output based on the `sum of the path weights`. Because, the path weight could be very small. For example, guess the `path weights from ID_3 to ID_5 are (0.1, 0.01, 0.0004)` this could happen (my dataset contains very small weight). So, I have to trust on the `path length` not the `sum of the path length`. Moreover, is it possible to get the output in this way 'ID_3 ID_5 2.11 or ID_5 ID_3 2.11` means `nodeA nodeB sum_of_the_path`?

Comment: Yes, you can also check in the existing graph (your graph) we have a path length=3 for `ID_7 and ID_5` but we are not getting the output because the `sum of the path is less than 2`. I can say that the `maximum` path weight for my dataset is `3 (for path length=3` but the minimum could be anything like `0.3, 0.003, etc,`  Waiting for your reply.

Comment: If you look at `mat`, you see that 2.11 has been calculated on index [3,6] or on index [6,3] of the matrix. I don't understand how you get path length = 3. The calculation already takes into account the weights.

Comment: path means, (ID_3 -> ID_1) 1st path, (ID_1 -> ID_2) 2nd path and (ID_2 -> ID_5) 3rd path. So, I am considering this a path length=3. At the same way (ID_3 -> ID_1) 1st path, (ID_1 -> ID_2) has path length =2.

Comment: The shortest path from 3 to 6 is given by :`get.shortest.paths(graph1,from=3,to=6)` and is `ID_3 ID_7 ID_4 ID_2 ID_5`. It doesn't have length 4 because it takes into account the weigths.

Comment: @Akib62, did it answer your question?

Comment: Actually, I need the ans in this formate `ID_3  ID_5     2.11; ID_5  ID_7     1.79`. `get.shortest.paths` function is not fulfill my purpose. But, I found another procedure (but not a good one) like I am using the `shortest.paths` function 2 times and then filtering the matrix, etc. BTW, thanks for your time ans answer. I have learned from your answer.